# How do you ignore a test subject in Intellij?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have several classes named `Test` in a project I am working on.  Is there a way I can get Intellij to ignore them when I navigate between the Test and Test Subject, so I don't get a popup menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible yet, please [submit a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).